# How to get element(responsecode) value from XML SOAP response in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap

Here is the response in SOAP:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://sdsds.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns0:ServiceResponse xmlns:ns0="ababa.co.ke/Schemas/SAFService.xsd">
            <ns0:ResponseHeader>
                <ns0:ResponseCode>1</ns0:ResponseCode>
                <ns0:ResponseMsg>999</ns0:ResponseMsg>
            </ns0:ResponseHeader>
        </ns0:ServiceResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And now I am trying to get **ResponseCode** value as below

```
//not working

$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$result = $obj->body->ServiceResponse->ResponseHeader->ResponseCode;
echo $result[0];
print_r($result);

//not working

$foo = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$bar = json_decode(json_encode($foo));
print_r($bar);
```

Can you please help or correct me where am I doing worng?

Comment: The data you are wanting to is within a node that has a `namespace` so you will need to use that namespace prefix when querying the dom.

Answer (score 1):

A Quick example of using a `namespace` when querying the SOAP response - done using regular DOMDocument and DOMXPath but should be fairly straightforward with SimpleXML

```
/*
    The uri used for the namespace does not necessarily as
    can be seen by the following nonsense uris.
*/
$strxml='<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="sdsds/xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <ns0:ServiceResponse xmlns:ns0="ababa.co.ke/Schemas/SAFService.xsd">
                    <ns0:ResponseHeader>
                        <ns0:ResponseCode>1</ns0:ResponseCode>
                        <ns0:ResponseMsg>999</ns0:ResponseMsg>
                    </ns0:ResponseHeader>
                </ns0:ServiceResponse>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

libxml_use_internal_errors( true ) ;
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=true;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->loadXML( $strxml );
$errors=libxml_get_errors();
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );



/* 
    Register the namespace - the prefix used here 
    does not necessarily need to match that used 
    in the SOAP response.
*/
$xp->registerNameSpace('x','ababa.co.ke/Schemas/SAFService.xsd');
$expr='//x:ServiceResponse/x:ResponseHeader/x:ResponseCode';

// run the query
$col=$xp->query( $expr );

// process results, if any.
if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->localName,'->',$node->nodeValue;
}else{
    echo 'XPath failed';
}
```

This will simply yield:

```
ResponseCode->1
```

---

**update using SimpleXML**

```
$dom=new SimpleXMLElement( $strxml );
$dom->registerXPathNamespace('x','ababa.co.ke/Schemas/SAFService.xsd');
$expr='//x:ServiceResponse/x:ResponseHeader/x:ResponseCode';
$col=$dom->xpath( $expr );
if( !empty( $col ) ){
    foreach( $col as $node )echo 'result -> '.$node.br;
}else{
    echo 'XPath failed';
}
```

Comment: $sxe=new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('c','example.org/chapter-title'); 
$result=$sxe->xpath('//c:title'); can't we do with SimpleXMLElement?

Comment: I don't use SimpleXML so I am unsure of the methods etc. What you have shown here is very similar to the example from the manual except that you have omitted the scheme from the uri

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Your code is perfect for my requirements. Thanks again. I even posted answer with SimpleXMLElement for your reference.

Comment: Do you know how to perform same operation using JavaScript?

Comment: yes, I believe I do. Have a look at [document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)

Comment: I have checked that but strongly feel that I can not code it in JavaScript as I am not good in JavaScript. :(

Comment: How would you make the SOAP request using Javascript?And why would you particularly wish to do it with JS? Perhaps accept the above if it helped?

Comment: I just called API with JavaScript, not with Soap request. Response is in SOAP format.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have done with **SimpleXMLElement** & got output exactly what I wished.

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="sdsds/xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <ns0:ServiceResponse xmlns:ns0="ababa.co.ke/Schemas/SAFService.xsd">
            <ns0:ResponseHeader>
                <ns0:ResponseCode>1</ns0:ResponseCode>
                <ns0:ResponseMsg>999</ns0:ResponseMsg>
            </ns0:ResponseHeader>
        </ns0:ServiceResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

$sxe=new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('x','ababa.co.ke/Schemas/SAFService.xsd');
$result=$sxe->xpath('//x:ServiceResponse/x:ResponseHeader/x:ResponseCode');
foreach ($result as $title)
{
   echo "ResponseCode:".$title . "<br>";
}
```

Output will be

```
ResponseCode:1
```